# Unable to upload or download files in any browser in Ubuntu Studio

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, upload, brave

I tried uploading a video to youtube via Google chrome but the chrome browser stopped working, seems stuck. can't click any of the tabs nor open a new one. can't edit my upload either. I thought it is the browser not working well so i uninstalled chrome. tried any of the browser, firefox, opera, brave, but to no avail. Downloading a file is the same. tried sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras but the problem persists. What should be done to fix this? looking forward to your response. thanks!!

Comment: Sounds like the storage device is completely full. If not, is there anything in `/var/log/syslog` that points to the issue? 

Comment: Have you checked the permissions of the destination directory? If it's not writable, all downloads would just abort, in all browsers.